# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to use dc.js to implement the crossfilter and d3. I am almost successful. When I run my code in JSFiddle, it works perfectly ok! But when i try to implement the exact code on the local system, it gives me **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null** error.

My code is

**trial1.js**

```js
var yearChart = dc.barChart('#year-chart');

//the data
var data = [
{date: "2015-10-01", type: "car", quantity: 3}];

var dispatch = crossfilter(data);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.quantity = +d.quantity;
    d.Year = d.date.getFullYear();
});

var dateDim = dispatch.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.date;
});
var productions = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return d.quantity;
});
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

yearChart.width(2000).height(200)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(productions)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
    .brushOn(false)
 .centerBar(true)
    .yAxisLabel("Productions per day")
 .xUnits(function(){return 10;});

yearChart.render();
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/colorbrewer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "trial1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="year-chart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

the line of code in ***d3.js*** that gives the error is ***this.node().textContent;***

Comment: you understand that you just imported correctly this line `<script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` the other imports are wrong....

Comment: please import correctly the other `scripts`

Comment: the other **scripts** are downloaded on the local system and saved in the js folder in the same directory.

Comment: Hey @Databases you need to import correctly so we can lookup whats wrong....

Comment: Hi @AlvaroJoao, done as you asked

Comment: got your problem...have need to make use all the dependencies of **trial1.js** and **d3.js** are loaded before using it.

Comment: ummm, im sorry. But how exactly do i do that?

Comment: Please check my answer, I think that what you gonna need to fix this issue for good and learn smth critical in web applications.

Comment: have you read the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue! `localy`
Just found out that the:

> ```
>  <div id="year-chart"></div>
> ```

was **misplaced**!

just try to setup **all** your html content **before** the `JS` files. And will work fine!

see the example:

obs: It was working on JSFiddle because the html (must) rend before the `js` scripts!

Hopefully will work for you too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Bar Chart Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
    <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
  
<div id="year-chart"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var yearChart = dc.barChart('#year-chart');

  //the data
  var data = [{
      date: "2015-10-01",
      customer: "BOASG",
      quantity: 3
  }];


  var dispatch = crossfilter(data);

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
  data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.quantity = +d.quantity;
      d.Year = d.date.getFullYear();
  });

  var dateDim = dispatch.dimension(function (d) {
      return d.date;
  });
  var productions = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
      return d.quantity;
  });
  var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
  window.alert(minDate);
  var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;
  window.alert(maxDate);

  yearChart.width(2000).height(200)
      .dimension(dateDim)
      .group(productions)
      .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
      .brushOn(false)
      .centerBar(true)
      .yAxisLabel("Productions per day")
      .xUnits(function () {
      return 10;
  });

  dc.renderAll();

</script>
 <!-- <div id="year-chart"></div>  if you set the code here you will be able to reproduce the issue.-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Databases check this answer

Comment: hi @alvaroJoao, I believe all the resources are being loaded before **trial1.js** because when I try to debug the script file, it runs perfectly until the last line. There appears to be some issue in **render()** and/or **renderAll()**. It keeps giving me the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null error**

Comment: Moreover, when I use the same code in **jsfiddle**, it appears to work there perfectly. I dont know what exactly am i missing here!

Comment: can you post the **exact** code you are using? or the JSfiddle?@Databases

Comment: here is the link to the jsfiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/Databases003/6Lp32oah/**

Comment: @Databases I have great news! I found what was your  problem

Comment: thanks a lot buddy! Works wonders! Just curious though, can i place the script in another file and import it?

Comment: yep! Np take care. @Databases

Answer (score 2):

I moved *.js file* link to the bottom of the html and **problem solved**.